# Are elements in a List supposed to have the same type?

Tags: python, c, list

> Wiki Definition - A list is any enumeration of a set of items.

Below given `Node`(C syntax) in a linked list,

```
typedef struct Node{
   void * data;
   struct Node * next;
}Node;
```

can accommodate any type element(`void *data`) in a list.

Below syntax,

```
>>>list  = [1, [1,2], 'a', [4,5]]
>>> type(list)
<class 'list'>
```

in python allows, `list` storing heterogeneous type elements.

From definition and implementation aspect, Is list suppose to allow elements of different type?

Comment: I recognize this isn't an exact duplicate, but the question I linked as a duplicate covers this exact point in most of the high ranked answers. `list`s _can_ be heterogenous, but generally _should_ be homogeneous, because it's rare that a sequence of things is meaningful when all the things are unrelated. `tuple`s, when used as lightweight classes, are naturally heterogeneous (the position in the `tuple` is important for defining the type, not just the order), but they can also be used as logical `list`s that happen to be immutable.

Comment: @ShadowRanger 1) When you say, *`list` can be heterogenous*, do you mean python allows such syntax? By definition, *list* MUST be homogenous. Is that what you are trying to say? 2) Do you understand wiki definition of *list* as homogenuous sequence?

Comment: I'm saying Python considers you to be an adult, and if you insist on using heterogeneous `list`s, it won't stop you. But it's rarely a good idea; it's fine if the values are different types with a common interface (a `list` of mixed `int` and `float` could be perfectly reasonable in some contexts), but if they're just wildly divergent types (a `str`, a `tuple`, an `int`, then `dict`, then three random classes), basically nothing will be able to process the `list` in a consistent way. Read the top answer on the linked question, it covers this better than I can in comments.

Comment: @overexchange: There are many slightly different definitions of the term *list*. Some require it to be homogeneous, others don't. The definition you quoted doesn't say lists are homogeneous, but it's irrelevant. The only definition that matters is the one in Python's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists): "Lists are mutable sequences, typically used to store collections of homogeneous items [...]". So they are typically homogeneous, but don't have to be.

Comment: Detail: `void * data;` does not accommodate any type element.  For example a `double complex` certainly cannot be saved distinctively in a `void *`. OTOH, a `void*` can hold any _pointer to an object_.

Comment: @chux  Introducing pointer members in list implementation helped me apply `memset`/`memcpy` as shown [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/147466/list-abstraction-using-array)